# SIGTRAP when calling the free() function

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm getting a SIGTRAP signal when trying to free an dynamically created array, and have no idea on why.

I'm allocating the array like this:

```
int* visited = (int*) malloc( l.nodeCount * sizeof(int));
```

(l.nodeCount is an integer. In the instance of the program I get this error, it is set to 12.)

And when I try to `free(visited)`, I get the SIGTRAP signal in the debugger.

The whole function is this one:

```
int Graph_GetSmallestPathCount(AdjacencyList l, int destination){

//One path if destination is root
if(destination == 0) return 1;

if(l.nodeCount == 0)
    return 0;

Queue reading = Queue_NewQueue();
Queue storing = Queue_NewQueue();

/*Allocates visited array*/
int* visited = (int*) calloc( l.nodeCount, sizeof(int));

/*Visited array initialization*/
int i;
for(i = 0; i < l.nodeCount; i++)
    visited[i] = 0;

/*Marks root node and enqueues it*/
visited[0] = 1;
Queue_Enqueue(&reading, 0);

//While there are nodes to read
while(!Queue_IsEmpty(reading))
{

    //Dequeues a node
    int v = Queue_Dequeue(&reading);

    //Gets it's adjacency list
    List* currentList = AdjacencyList_GetAdjacentNodes(l, v);
    listCell* auxCell = currentList->head->next;

    //While there are nodes in it's adjacency list
    while(auxCell != NULL){

        //Enqueues it if it has not been visited
        if(visited[auxCell->data] == 0){
            Queue_Enqueue(&storing, auxCell->data);
        }

        //Adds to the paths to that node
        visited[auxCell->data] += visited[v];

        auxCell = auxCell->next;
    }

    //When the queue ends
    if(Queue_IsEmpty(reading)){

        //If the destination has been reached, return
        if(visited[destination] > 0){
            Queue_Destroy(&reading);
            Queue_Destroy(&storing);
            return visited[destination];
        }
        else{
            //Switch queues
            Queue_Destroy(&reading);

            reading = storing;
            storing = Queue_NewQueue();
        }
    }

}

//Destination has not been reached before end of algorithms. Deallocate everything and return 0
free(visited);
Queue_Destroy(&reading);
Queue_Destroy(&storing);

return 0;
```

}

Sorry for the lack of comments, I did this on a run and didn't put any in. Also sorry for the printf overload, I put them there while trying to pinpoint the problem.
EDIT: I cleaned it up a little.

The weird thing is that the program works for certain inputs and doesn't for others.

Hope someone can help me out =D

Comment: Maybe something in your code is messing up the heap.  Also a double `free()` could cause that error.

Comment: Might the value of `auxCell->data` in `visited[auxCell->data] += visited[v];` be equal to or greater than `l.nodeCount`?

Comment: It can't, as it can only be a node inside the graph. I've made sure of that.

Comment: Try outputting the value of the [] number every time you assign something to visited[n] so you can see if you ever exceed the allocated memory. I'm guessing that's happening at some point. And fwiw you don't need to initialize the array if you use calloc, as it already initializes the allocated memory to all zeros.

Comment: You probably have a severe [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Comment: Things like this can give you this error: `char* a = malloc(size); memcpy(a, some_src, size+1); free(a)`. As Basile Starynkevitch, it can be some kind of mem corruption like this one.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you why you get a `SIGTRAP` as you haven't published a minimal example.

However, I can tell you how to find out out yourself:

1. Make your program readable. Use one instruction per line. The `indent` tool is your friend. Sure, that won't fix the bug, but it will make it easier for you to find it.
2. Don't `malloc` like that. There is no need to cast the return value of `malloc`, and using `calloc(l.nodeCount, sizeof (int));` or similar is more readable anyway.
3. What `SIGTRAP` actually means is you've hit a breakpoint instruction. No doubt what's actually happening is that you've jumped to something which is not your code, and might not be code at all, but contains the binary code for a breakpoint. Why did that happen? The normal cause would be memory corruption, particularly stack corruption. I'm guessing `free()` is corrupting its own stack. And I'd guess the reason for that is because you are (somewhere) writing to memory outside the memory you've allocated. To test this, run your program with the `malloc()/calloc()` immediately followed by the `free()` and an `exit(0)`. If that works, you know the issue is something you are doing between.
4. We can't tell what you are doing between because you haven't (thankfully) posted the full program, but try running it under `valgrind`. When you get an out-of-range write, `valgrind` will normally pick it up. Fix every `valgrind` warning. That doesn't guarantee a solution, but will find one 95% of the time in my experience.
5. Also note that `return visited[destination];` appears to exit the function without `free()`-ing `visited`, which is thus a memory leak.

Comment: As I said, sorry for all those prints. They are the only occasions where there are more than one instruction per line.

Comment: There, I cleaned it up a little.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't call malloc() like that. `l.nodeCount * sizeof(int)` could potentially exceed INT_MAX, and you'll either have a security hole or if you're lucky, a crash.

Instead, use `calloc(l.nodeCount, sizeof(int))`.

You should also check the return value of `malloc` or `calloc` for NULL in the event your program runs out of memory to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. There was indeed a chance that on specific cases the array would be created with one element less than it should. My bad.

Thanks to all who helped =D